# Видна ли схема без объектов

Tags: oracle, plsql, метаданные

Может ли исчезнуть схема из списка схем в SQL Developer и PL/SQL Developer, если не на один объект из нее у меня нет прав. Исчезла схема из списка, думаю связано с этим. Какие еще могут быть причины, кроме ее удаления?

Comment: А где вы там видите схемы?

Comment: Список пользователей - схем. В SQL Developer - Scheme Browser, в PL/SQL Developer - список слева. Но вопрос: Будет ли видна схема, если по правам не доступен ни один ее объект?

Comment: "если по правам не доступен ни один ее объект?" - тут часто нужно уточнять, по каким правам. Права могут быть даны напрямую, через rule, через public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, схема будет видна:

```
show user
USER is "SYS"

create user test1 identified externally account lock;
User TEST1 created.
```

---

```
show user
USER is "ME"

select username, user_id, sysdate, created 
from dba_users where username like upper('test%');

USERNAME                  USER_ID SYSDATE              CREATED            
---------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------
TEST1                         188 2018-05-18  10:19:30 2018-05-18  10:18:24
```

Представление `dba_users` доступно всем через публичный синоним:

```
select owner, object_name, object_type 
from dba_objects where object_name='DBA_USERS'
;

OWNER      OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYPE       
---------- -------------------- -------------------
SYS        DBA_USERS            VIEW               
PUBLIC     DBA_USERS            SYNONYM
```

Поэтому, возможная причина ошибки в инструментах, которые указаны в вопросе .